# Accessing Sharedpreference throws android.res.content.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have *2 activities* in the project namely *Main_Activity* and *Settings_Activity*.

Tried adding a new *SettinsActivity* from the android studio but *deleted* it and added a *blank activity* and named it *Settings_Activity*
Have the following code in the *OnCreate()* of *Settings_Activity*

```
 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    try {
        pollTime = sharedpreferences.getInt("pollTime", 16);
        logClearCount = sharedpreferences.getInt("logClearCount", 6);
        eTPollTime.setText(pollTime);
        eTLogClearCount.setText(logClearCount);
        sharedpreferences.getBoolean("errorAlarm", false);
        cbErrorAlarm.setChecked(errAlarm);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        tvDescription.setText(ex.toString());
    }
```

Here I catch a `android.res.content.Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException` because `pollTime` is integer and passing to `setText` without using `String.valueOf`

Comment: R you try **eTPollTime.setText(String.valuof(pollTime));** and **eTLogClearCount.setText(String.valuof(logClearCount));** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eTPollTime.setText(pollTime);
eTLogClearCount.setText(logClearCount);
```

This will make the system look for a ressource in your xml ressource files with ressource id with the value pollTime or logClearCount (int). This ressource will not exist and you get an exception.